# How to switch between themes in Ant design v4 dynamically?

Tags: css, reactjs, less, antd

I'd like to implement **switching between dark/light theme dynamically** with Ant design v4.

It's possible to customize the theme with other CSS/LESS imports as it's written here:
https://ant.design/docs/react/customize-theme#Use-dark-theme

But I'm not sure how to switch between those themes dynamically from the code. I have a variable in my React app (`darkMode`) which indicates if the dark theme is currently used. I have to provide correct CSS files when this variable is changed. But I can't import CSS dynamically only when some condition is fulfilled, because it's not way how the imports work.

I tried to do something messy with `require` like in the following code, but it's a very very bad approach and it's still not working properly (because CSS is injected but probably not withdrawn.
):

```js
const Layout = () => {
  ...
  useEffect(() => {
    if (darkMode === true) {
      require("./App.dark.css")
    } else {
      require("./App.css")
    }
  }, [darkMode])

  return (
    <Home />
  )
}
```

It should be possible to switch themes somehow because it's already implemented in Ant design docs (https://ant.design/components/button/):

[image: Theme switch in Antd docs]

Do you have any idea how to do it?

Thanks!

Comment: Is the website at https://ant.design/components/button/ opensource? I can't seem to find it in their repositories. Many of their websites are opensource. It would be very useful to see how they implement this on their own site.

Comment: The best option for me is using post-css plugin as described in https://dev.to/maqi1520/using-the-postcss-plugin-let-your-webapp-support-dark-mode-1nnp. It creates additional .dark class with dark colors only. Basically the class can be cosindered as a diff between default and dark theme. It's easy to write toogle component and doesn't have downsides like client processing of the stylesheet (slow) or flash when loading or switching. It's compatbile with customize-cra. Caveat is that there is issue with the build - sometimes it produces broken css. Trying to resolve those. Will add comment.

Answer (score 5):

This is what I am using for now -

PS -

1. I don't know if this will yield optimal bundle size.
2. changing theme results in a page reload.

---

make a folder called "themes" - it would have 6 files -> dark-theme.css, dark-theme.jsx, light-theme.css, light-theme.jsx, use-theme.js, theme-provider.jsx. Each of them is described below.

dark-theme.css

```
import "~antd/dist/antd.dark.css";
```

dark-theme.jsx

```
import "./dark-theme.css";
const DarkTheme = () => <></>;
export default DarkTheme;
```

light-theme.css

```
@import "~antd/dist/antd.css";
```

light-theme.jsx

```
import "./light-theme.css";
const LightTheme = () => <></>;
export default LightTheme;
```

---

use-theme.js *A custom hook that different components can use* -

```
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";

const DARK_MODE = "dark-mode";

const getDarkMode = () => JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem(DARK_MODE)) || false;

export const useTheme = () => {
  const [darkMode, setDarkMode] = useState(getDarkMode);

  useEffect(() => {
    const initialValue = getDarkMode();
    if (initialValue !== darkMode) {
      localStorage.setItem(DARK_MODE, darkMode);
      window.location.reload();
    }
  }, [darkMode]);

  return [darkMode, setDarkMode];
};
```

---

theme-provider.jsx

```
import { lazy, Suspense } from "react";
import { useTheme } from "./use-theme";

const DarkTheme = lazy(() => import("./dark-theme"));
const LightTheme = lazy(() => import("./light-theme"));

export const ThemeProvider = ({ children }) => {
  const [darkMode] = useTheme();

  return (
    <>
      <Suspense fallback={<span />}>
        {darkMode ? <DarkTheme /> : <LightTheme />}
      </Suspense>
      {children}
    </>
  );
};
```

---

change index.js to -

```
ReactDOM.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <ThemeProvider>
      <App />
    </ThemeProvider>
  </React.StrictMode>,
  document.getElementById("root")
);
```

---

now, in my navbar suppose I have a switch to toggle the theme. This is what it would look like -

```
const [darkMode, setDarkMode] = useTheme();
<Switch checked={darkMode} onChange={setDarkMode} />
```

Comment: Very nice. Thanks for the code.

Answer (score 2):

you must create 2 components

the first one :

```
import './App.dark.css'

const DarkApp =() =>{
   //the app container
}
```

and the second :

```
import './App.light.css'

const LightApp =() =>{
   //the app container
}
```

and create HOC to handle `darkMode` like this :

```
const AppLayout = () =>{
const [isDark , setIsDark] = useState(false);


return (
 <>
  {
  isDark ? 
    <DarkApp /> :
      <LightApp />
  }
 </>
 )
}
```

Comment: It doesn't work just like that - both components are loaded. You need lazy loading as described bellow.

Answer (score 2):

ANTD internally uses CSS variables for the "variable.less" file. We can override these variables to make the default variables have dynamic values at runtime.

This is one way it can be achieved:

app-colors.less file:

```
:root{
    --clr-one: #fff;
    --clr-two: #000;
    --clr-three: #eee;
}

// Dark theme colors
[data-thm="dark"]{
    --clr-one: #f0f0f0;
    --clr-two: #ff0000;
    --clr-three: #fff;
}
```

We can now override the default ANTD variables in antd-overrides.less file:

```
@import <app-colors.less file-path>;

@primary-color: var(--clr-one);
@processing-color: var(--clr-two);
@body-background: var(--clr-three);
```

We usually import the antd.less file to get the antd styles, We would change that to "antd.variable.less"(to use css variables).

index.less file:

```
@import "~antd/dist/antd.variable.less";
@import <antd-overrides.less file-path>;
```

Now we need to toggle the "data-thm" attribute on a parent container(body tag recommended) to change the set of CSS variables that get used.

```
const onThemeToggle = (themeType) => {
  const existingBodyAttribute = document.body.getAttribute("data-thm");
  if (themeType === "dark" && existingBodyAttribute !== "dark") {
    document.body.setAttribute("data-thm", "dark");
  } else if (themeType === "light" && existingBodyAttribute) {
    document.body.removeAttribute("data-thm");
  }
};
```

The above piece of code can be called on a Theme toggle button or during component mount.

Answer (score 1):

In [Ant's example](https://ant.design/docs/react/customize-theme#Use-dark-or-compact-theme) one suggestion is to import your "dark mode" CSS or LESS file into your main style sheet.

```
// inside App.css
@import '~antd/dist/antd.dark.css';
```

Instead of trying to toggle stylesheets, the "dark" styles are combined with base styles in one stylesheet. There are different ways to accomplish this, but the common pattern will be:

1. have a `dark-mode` selector of some sort in your CSS
2. put that selector in your HTML
3. have a way to toggle it on or off.

Here is a working example:

https://codesandbox.io/s/compassionate-elbakyan-f7tun?file=/src/App.js

[image: dark mode toggle]

In this example, toggling the state of `darkMode` will add or remove a `dark-mode` className to the top level container.

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import "./styles.css";

export default function App() {
  const [darkMode, setDarkMode] = useState(false);

  return (
    <div className={`App ${darkMode && "dark-mode"}`}>
      <label>
        <input
          type="checkbox"
          checked={darkMode}
          onChange={() => setDarkMode((darkMode) => !darkMode)}
        />
        Dark Mode?
      </label>
      <h1>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
    </div>
  );
}
```

If `darkMode` is true, and the `dark-mode` className is present, those styles will be used:

```
h1 {
  padding: 0.5rem;
  border: 3px dotted red;
}

.dark-mode {
  background: black;
  color: white;
}

.dark-mode h1 {
  border-color: aqua;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Ant Design newly start to support dynamic theme support. But its on experimental usage. You can find details on this [link](https://ant.design/docs/react/customize-theme-variable).

Comment: do you have an example which shows switching between dark/light theme dynamically...

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30084279)

Answer (score 0):

Conditional require won't block using previously required module. So, whenever your condition matches the require will available in your app. So, your both required module will be used. Instead of requiring them, insert stylesheet and remove to toggle between them:

```
const head = document.head
const dark = document.createElement('link')
const light = document.createElement('link')
dark.rel = 'stylesheet'
light.rel = 'stylesheet'
dark.href = 'antd.dark.css'
light.href = 'antd.light.css'

useEffect(() => {
  const timer = setTimeout(() => {
    if (darkMode) {
      if (head.contains(light)) {
        head.removeChild(light)
      }
      head.appendChild(dark)
    } else {
      if (head.contains(dark)) {
        head.removeChild(dark)
      }
      head.appendChild(light)
    }
  }, 500)
 return () => clearTimeout(timer)
}, [darkMode])
```

Answer (score 0):

This [package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/antd-theme-vars) will help you to export and use theme vars without losing performance

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/32967899)

Answer (score -3):

1. Using less compiler in runtime:
   https://medium.com/@mzohaib.qc/ant-design-dynamic-runtime-theme-1f9a1a030ba0
2. Import less code into wrapper
   https://github.com/less/less.js/issues/3232

```
.any-scope {
    @import url('~antd/dist/antd.dark.less');
}
```

Comment: How to do this using create react app?

Comment: Compiling less during runtime isn't as performant. Someone tried many methods and found the most performant way was to use cssvars: https://github.com/ant-design/ant-design/issues/23371#issuecomment-634698379